# Rendered preview stopped working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, linux

I'm not sure what happend... I had CUDA enabled so long as I opened Blender as root, but not only has that disappeared, my "rendered" preview no longer works. For example if I open a brand new project with just the cube, switch to cycles, and select rendered, I get this:

[image: rendered preview]

If I actually render the project by clicking the render button, it works... I just can't preview it anymore.

- Blender 2.75
- OS: Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit
- Cinnamon Version: 2.2.16
- Linux Kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic
- Processor: Intel Core i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40 GHz x 4
- Memory: 15.7 GiB
- Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13bb

I haven't changed anything outside of some automatic system updates. Any ideas?

Comment: Just so you know, the name of your graphics card isn't "NVIDIA Corporation Device". You should probably actually look up the name of your GPU

Comment: Well that's what it says in the system info. It's the PNY Quadro K620 if that helps.